# SPLIT file by Script (bash, cpp) - numbers in columns

Tags: bash, split, awk, conditional-statements

I have files with some columns filled by numbers (float). I would need to split these files according to the value in one of the columns (can set as the first one). This means, when

```
a b c
```

in my file the value `c` fullfils `0.05<=c<=0.1` then create the file named `c` and copy the whole columns there which fullfils the `c`-condition...
is this possible? I can something small with bash, awk, something also with c++.
I have searched for some solutions but - I can the data sort of course and only read the first number of the line..
I don't know.
Please, very please.
Thank you
Jane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned awk, the basic rule in awk is 'match a line (either by default or with a regexp, condition or line number)' AND 'do something because you found a match'.

awk uses values like $1, $2, $3 to indicate which column in the current line of data it is looking at. $0 refers to the whole line. So ...

```
awk '
 BEGIN{
    afile="afile.txt"
    bfile="bfile.txt"
    cfile="cfile.txt"
 }

{
  # test c value between .05 and .1
  if ($3 >= 0.05 && $3 <= 0.1) print $0 > cfile
} inputData
```

Note that I am testing the value of the third column (c in your example). You can use $2 to test b column, etc.

If you don't know about the sort of condition test I have included `>= 0.5 && $3 <= 0.1` you'll have some learning ahead of you.

Questions in the form of 1. I have this input, 2. I want this output. 3. (but) I'm getting this output, 4. with this code .... {code here} .... have a much better chance of getting a reasonable response in a reasonable amount of time ;-)

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly:

```
awk '{print > $3}' file ...
```